# Is there an expression for "turn of phrase" in Spanish?

Tags: modismos, idiomático

Something with a little more of the poetic flavor of "turn of phrase" than, say, "forma de hablar" (manner of speaking / figure of speech) or "expresión", that is.

To clarify, I'm thinking of this sense of the expression, which refers to an interesting or compelling phrasing, rather than the person behind it:

> #### turn of phrase (plural turns of phrase)
>
> (idiomatic) An expression which is worded in a distinctive way,
> especially one which is particularly memorable or artful.

Some examples:

> The title is, as the author quickly admits, “a turn of phrase, not the
> literal truth

[[source](http://www.economist.com/news/books-and-arts/21577348-gloomy-convincing-account-developed-worlds-problems-horror-story)]

> JAVIER SOLANA, the European Union's top foreign-policy honcho,
> recently offered a neat turn of phrase to explain the importance that
> Europeans attach to the past. Ponder the phrase “that's history”, and
> what it implies on either side of the Atlantic, he suggested. When
> Americans say something is “history”, they mean it is no longer
> relevant. When Europeans say the same thing, “they usually mean the
> opposite”.

[[source](http://www.economist.com/node/9185774)]

> President Barack Obama said that “cap and trade” was “just one way of
> skinning the cat.” It is a common expression, used to imply that there
> are plenty of ways of doing something. But a closer look at its
> origins reveals it is a somewhat unsavoury turn of phrase.

[[source](http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2013/10/idioms-and-political-speech)]

Comment: El bien comunicado?

Comment: Could you give more context or a full sentence? For example, I would translate the example in wordreference *"'Significant other', meaning 'partner', now that's an interesting turn of phrase!"* as *"'Media naranja' para decir 'pareja', ¡eso sí que es una expresión interesante!"*. For other cases the word "palabra" may be enough.

Comment: I think, at least in 2 of the 3 examples, you could use the expression *"juego de palabras*" (wordplay). But let's wait and see what others come up with for your 3 examples!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Expresión* or *frase* is correct for these 3 examples, there is not an idiom or phrasal verb in Spanish.

Looking on internet I have seen many examples but with an adjective before:

> a vivid turn of phrase >> una frase deslumbrante
>
> a homely turn of phrase >> una frase coloquial / una expresión coloquial

[linguee.es](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/turn+of+phrase.html)

> she has a picturesque turn of phrase >> tiene una manera pintoresca de expresarse / usa expresiones pintorescas

[oxforddictionaies](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/traducir/ingles-espanol/turn)

So your 3 examples would be:

- a turn of phrase >> una expresión
- a neat turn of phrase >> una expresión coherente
- it is a somewhat unsavoury turn of phrase >> este comentario es un poco desafortunado / es un comentario feo / es una expresión un poco desafortunada / no es una expresión muy afortunada.

---

If the *turn of phrase* is refering to a memorable idiom, it can be translated as *frases hechas* / *refranes* / *dicho* or *modismo*

> a Spanish turn of phrases >> una frase hecha en español / un refrán español / un dicho español / un modismo español *(it depends of the phrase, all translations are not used for the same)*

---

For the second meaning of turn of phrase [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+turn+of+phrase)

> the ability to express yourself well

Depending if it is used on the favour of the speaker or not here are some options:

- Labia

> f. Elocuencia y gracia para hablar y convencer a los demás:
>   *este político tiene mucha labia.*
>   
>   [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/labia)

---

- Embaucar / Embaucador

> tr. Engañar a alguien, aprovechándose de su inexperiencia o ingenuidad:
>   *con semejante labia es capaz de embaucar al más avispado.*
>   
>   [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/embaucar)

---

- Savia

> Persona o elemento que comunica energía y vitalidad:
>   *su alegría es la savia de la casa.*
>   
>   [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/savia)

---

- Deslumbrar

> Asombrar, encantar, fascinar:
>   *me deslumbra con sus ocurrencias.*
>   
>   [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/deslumbrar)

---

Sometimes you would have to use other words in Spanish to say the same.

> Her vocabulary and her turn of phrase >> su vocabulario y su fraseología.

(About a book)

> With these elements, and a very precise, rich and playful turn of phrase, very typical of young people >> Con estos elementos, y con un lenguaje preciso, rico y juguetón, muy propio de la gente joven.

[linguee.es](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/turn+of+phrase.html)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't actually aware of that sense of the expression—I had the first definition in mind, but that's good to know. I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here a pair of suggestions:

- *Somebody has a nice turn of frase* means *alguien sabe expresarse (bien o bonito)*; when the *turn of phrase* bears a positive connotation, it could also be also *elocuencia*, *ser elocuente*.

Perhaps it might be helpful

- *vena poética* (poetic vein).